# How Ejb object make associated entity bean restore the last content before passivation

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0, ejb-passivation

For example in this scenario : A client has reference to an EjbOBject which is associated to an Entity bean ,after long time without using this bean , container decides to passivate the bean and kick it to the pool. Making the Ejb not assoc with any bean ,after a while client decides to use the passivated entity bean ! .so the container  activates or creates a entity bean and associated it to the ejb object .my qustion is how the ejb object makes this new bean restore the ancient content ?